# Do computational geometers use Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: soft-question, oc.optimization-and-control, computational-geometry

Can anyone point me to an example of a problem that (more or less) originated in computational geometry whose solution requires the use of Lagrange multipliers (or Kuhn-Tucker conditions, or dual variables in a linear program, etc.)?  I have not been able to find such an example in any of the literature that I own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convex optimization method for constructing a set of points in the plane with prescribed (combinatorial) Delaunay triangulation is given in

Euclidean structures on simplicial surfaces and hyperbolic volume
I Rivin - Annals of Mathematics, 1994

Answer (score 4):

Two examples, neither a direct hit on what you seek, I think.
But maybe they will trigger connections for others to answer better.

> (1) Moody T. Chu and Matthew M. Lin.
>   "Low-Dimensional Polytope Approximation and Its Applications to Nonnegative Matrix Factorization."
>   *SIAM J. Sci. Comput.*, 30(3), 1131–1155.
>   ([Journal link](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/070680436).)

This paper's focus is approximating a polytope with another
with fewer facets.
At the heart of their work is a convex-hull fitting problem, for which
they use Lagrange multipliers.

---

[image: CHFitting]

          

<sup>(Image from [Chu PDF presentation](http://www.niss.org/sites/default/files/Chu_eccr_2007_February.pdf).)</sup>

---

---

> (2) Kojima, Masakazu, Nimrod Megiddo, and Shinji Mizuno. "A Lagrangian Relaxation Method for Approximating the Analytic Center of a Polytope." IBM Thomas J. Watson Research Division, 1992.

Whether calculating the analytic center of a polytope "originated 
in computational geometry" is debatable.

Finally, Lagrange multipliers find use in robotics, again not really
originating in computational goemetry.